# flipping multiple cards in React (functional component)

Tags: reactjs

I successfully implemented an answer by Mosh Feu ([react-card-flip library on multiple cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67660422/react-card-flip-library-on-multiple-cards/67660743#67660743?newreg=33727758d8d54e12befbe558daa47e48)) in creating multiple flipping cards, just changed it to functional component and all is working just great! I do not understand though why we need to use Set inside a Set (let flipped = new Set(flip)):

```
const Projects = () => {
  const [flip, setFlip] = useState(new Set())
  
  const flipCard = (id) => {
    return (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let flipped = new Set(flip)
    if (flipped.has(id)) {
      flipped.delete(id)
      } else {
          flipped.add(id)
      }
      setFlip(flipped)
    }
  }

  return (
    <CardsWrapper>
      <Card
        flip={flip.has(1)}
        onClick={flipCard(1)}
      >
        <Front>
          <Image src={safety} alt="safety" />
        </Front>
        <Back>
          <h2>This is some text to be shown at the back of the SAFETY</h2> 
        </Back>
      </Card>
      <Card
        flip={flip.has(2)}
        onClick={flipCard(2)}
      >
        <Front>
          <Image src={church} alt="church" />
        </Front>
        <Back>
          <h2>This is some text to be shown at the back of the CHURCH</h2> 
        </Back>
      </Card>
    <CardsWrapper>
  )
}
```

If I try to use add/delete/check values in the Set declared in the state, it does not work:

```
const flipCard = (id) => {
        return (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (flip.has(id)) {
          flip.delete(id)
          } else {
              flip.add(id)
          }
          setFlip(flip)
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Set` in javascript has two constructors.

```
new Set()
new Set(iterable)
```

The second one is what is being used in your code. The idea is to create a new set from an already existing set. When you do `let flipped = new Set(flip)` a new set is created with already existing flipped cards.

Below is an example use case. The first example already has an item in the set and in the end, it gets 3 items. The last example is the regular use case and it will have 2 items as expected.

```js
let a = new Set();
a.add(4);
let b = new Set(a);
b.add(1);
b.add(2);
a = b;
console.log(a.size);

let x = new Set();
let y = new Set();
y.add(1);
y.add(2);
x = y;
console.log(x.size);
```